# show description in listview instead of opening a new activity

Tags: android, listview

currently my app has a listview and each listrow contains one word, and onclicking that listrow i open a new activity and show detail of that word which is not more than 5-10 words.

i recently saw in PAYTM app that onclicking a listrow they show the details of that coupon at that place itself instead of showing the details in a new activity. like this image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AAKO.png

i searched very well but i didnt get any way to show the data like how its shown in the above image. i am able to dispay a list each list row opening a new activity but not the way its shown in the image

sorry cany post image as i dont have 10rep

Comment: This question needs to be filled out. Is that animated? What have you tried so far? Do you know what an Adapter is in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Inflate a custom row to your list adapter and set the default visibility for description page as `gone`. When user click on the list item just set the visibility to that row as `visible`.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply Toast the details onclick:
Following if the code:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";    
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

See the following link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html